# UISearchBar in UINavigationBar, prevent from hiding

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

I have put `UISearchBar` in `UINavigationBar`, but the problem is when I click on `UISearchBar`, `UINavigatioBar` hides, how to fix this?

Code:

```
searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 44)];

searchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];

searchDisplayController.delegate = self;
searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self;

self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;
```

-(void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar

```
-(void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar

{
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = NO;
}
```

Comment: please post the code of - (void) searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar delegate method ..

Comment: Edited, I use - (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString

Comment: but where you reload tableview? and also you set searchbar in this above method??

Comment: I misunedrstood you, I added 
-(void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar in question

I set searchbar in viewDidLoad